# Можно ли считать описку ошибкой?

Tags: общие-вопросы, грамотная-речь

Я хочу посоветоваться с уважаемым ученым сообществом. Как вы думаете: можно ли считать описку ошибкой? Например, должен ли учитель русского языка снижать оценки за явную описку? Ведь достаточно большой процент людей страдают дислексией (и я в том числе), а еще многие делают опечатки при наборе текста на компьютере. Именно опечатки, а не грамматические ошибки (а самое обидное, когда знаешь, как пишется слово, но случайно тыкаешь в А вместо О или что-то в этом духе))).
Что вы об этом думаете?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

При оценивании контрольных работ описка за ошибку не считается. Так написано в нормах выставления оценок. Если вместо слова *дом* ученик написал *дам* - это описка. Но если это написание в безударном положении (*дама* вместо *дома*), то скорее учитель посчитает это за ошибку. Да и как отличить в таком случае описку от ошибки?

Comment: >Да и как отличить в таком случае описку от ошибки?

Например, если эти "дома" в тексте встрчаются с десяток раз, а ошибка только в одном случае. Хотя и тут на усмотрение проверяющего.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в таких спорных случаях, все зависит от компетентности  педагога : насколько он знает способности этого ученика.Если этот ученик хорошо учится , вряд ли педагог посчитает описку за ошибку.

Comment: Что значит "если этот ученик хорошо учится"? А если он плохо учится? О какой объективности оценивания тогда можно говорить? Мне кажется, есть определённый перечень "вариантов написания", которые не относятся к орфографическим ошибкам. И изменение звукового облика слова (о котором Вы, Серж, говорите) - это как раз такой случай.

Comment: Ну почему же? Я,например, очень часто механически пишу в слово "товарищи" окончание "е". Это же не ошибка. В таких случаях, хороший педагог будет знать кому считать это за ошибку, а кому - нет.